# How can i pass parameters to a Common Table Expression inside a sp?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, common-table-expression

I want to rewrite a functioning, but slow stored procedure using CTE (common table Expression)

I have a big stored procedure where i build the nececary SQL dynamicaly based on parameter used. Currently there are 27 parameters, i compose the SQL string that i execute at the end it looks like:

```
    DECLARE @SqlWhereClause NVARCHAR(MAX)  
SET @SqlWhereClause = ' WHERE ([InTimeStamp] BETWEEN ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), @fromDate, 120) + ''' AND ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), @toDate, 120) + ''')'

IF @showOnlyErrors = '1'  
   BEGIN
     SET @SqlWhereClause += ' AND Status = ''Error'''  
    END

IF LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(@docNo))) > 0  
  BEGIN  
    IF @matchExact = '1'   
      BEGIN
         SET @SqlWhereClause += ' AND DocumentNumber = ''' + @docNo + ''''  
      END
   ELSE
    BEGIN   
        SET @SqlWhereClause += ' AND (contains([DocumentNumber],'''+ @docNo +'''))'
    END 
  END
```

At the end, i add the pagination and transform it to the final formSQL:

```
    IF CONVERT(int, LTRIM(RTRIM(@takeRows))) > 0   
   BEGIN
     SET @SqlOrderByClause += ' OFFSET ' + @rowNumberToSkip +' ROWS FETCH NEXT '+ @takeRows +' ROWS ONLY '
     Set @RowCount = ' Select @totalRecords = count(1) from  dbo.Messages WITH (NOLOCK) ' + @SqlWhereClause
   END

    SET @SQL = @SqlSelect + @SqlFrom + @SqlWhereClause + @SqlOrderByClause + ' ; '  + @RowCount  
    PRINT @SQL  
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, @params, @totalRecords OUTPUT
```

Everithing is working like a charm. No problems. Only performance problems. To solve one of it, i would try to use CTE (common table extpression)

But this is not working:

```
   With DataSQL AS
    (@SqlSelect + @SqlFrom + @SqlWhereClause + @SqlOrderByClause),

   - incorrect syntax near @SqlSelect - Expecting '(' or Select.
```

I also tried this one:

```
     WITH DataSQL AS 
     ( Select @SqlSelect    From @SqlFromFast   
    Where @SqlWhereClause   Order By @SqlOrderByClause),
```

here i get:

```
    An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'Order'
```

Any idea? Or is it not possible to use CTE with multiple variables? All i found until now are simply queries with one, maybe two variables.

Comment: what is slow? building the dynamic sql or executing the dynamic sql?

Comment: Executinng takes long. Also because the rowcount take almost as mutch as the query itself. I checked it in the execution plan, it had 50%/50%

Comment: Did you take a look at the execution plan? Does SSMS suggest any indexes?

Comment: The problem with the indexes are that at the one side we have many Contains (Like) searches where an index don't help and on the other side there are typical 12-15 search criterias used more often from the total of 27. But also the others are in use. This table is already an aggregated table and it is use only for monitoring purpose, so Update is non existing, Insert is done via a batch (every 5 minutes) and delete is done via a job (delete all older than 52 weeks).

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
WITH DataSQL AS
(
     SELECT   @SqlSelect SqlSelect
     ,        @SqlFromFast SqlFromFast
     ,        etcetera
)
```

Make sure you give aliases, or it won't work. I doubt it will help your performance issues though. You could try to use a temp table, that's usually quicker. you could also try to use inner variables:

```
DECLARE @Select VARCHAR(MAX) = @SQLSelect
```

And use those instead, that may help the optimizer, though that depends on your data.

Comment: The biggest bottlenmeck i detected at the moment is the second query for the  @RowCount. It takes around the same time as the query itself.

Comment: The variable SqlSelect contains more than a column, same as the SqlWhereClause variable. 
SET @SqlSelect = '
 [RecordId],
 [TransactionId], 
 [Status],
 [InTimeStamp],
 [OutTimeStamp],
 [Doctype],
 [DocumentNumber],
 [DocFormat], .....